# How to transform array of arrays into columns in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this below

```text
+-----------------------------+
|       Item                  |
+-----------------------------+
|[[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [g,h,i]]  |
+--------------------+--------+
```

How to transform it into below tables?

```text
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

I have tried using the `explode` and `withColumn` function

```text
a b c
a e c
a h c
d b c
d e c
d h c
... (many other combinations)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explode only the first level array then you can select array elements as columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], ["g","h","i"]],)],
    ["Item"]
)

df.withColumn("Item", F.explode("Item")).select(
    *[F.col("Item")[i].alias(f"col_{i}") for i in range(3)]
).show()

#+-----+-----+-----+
#|col_0|col_1|col_2|
#+-----+-----+-----+
#|    a|    b|    c|
#|    d|    e|    f|
#|    g|    h|    i|
#+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

@blackbishop improving your answer...

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], ["g","h","i", "j"]],)],
    ["data"]
)

df.show(20, False)

df = df.withColumn("data1", F.explode("data"))
df.select('data1').show()

# Row(max(size(data1))=4) ---> 4
max_size = df.select(F.max(F.size('data1'))).collect()[0][0]


df.select(
    *[F.col("data1")[i].alias(f"col_{i}") for i in range(max_size)]
).show()



+------------------------------------+
|data                                |
+------------------------------------+
|[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i, j]]|
+------------------------------------+

+------------+
|       data1|
+------------+
|   [a, b, c]|
|   [d, e, f]|
|[g, h, i, j]|
+------------+

+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_0|col_1|col_2|col_3|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    b|    c| null|
|    d|    e|    f| null|
|    g|    h|    i|    j|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```